# Redirect all messages from dhcpd to its own log file?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, isc-dhcp, syslogd

I'd like to redirect all messages from dhcpd to their own log file, rather than having them appear in `/var/log/messages`.

Here is the configuration on `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
!dhcpd
*.*                     /var/log/dhcpd.log
```

The messages are redirected to `dhcpd.log`, but they're also going to `/var/log/messages`.

What's the configuration to exclude them from `/var/log/messages`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!-prog' specification will match any message but the ones from that program:

```
!-dhcpd
*.err;kern.*;auth.notice;authpriv.none;mail.crit         /dev/console
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none       /var/log/messages
......

!dhcpd
*.*                     /var/log/dhcpd.log
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :).
One thing that also works, is to add the specification at the end of the filter, like this: `*.=info; *.=notice; *.=warn; auth,authpriv.none; cron,daemon.none; mail,news.none; !-dhcpd -/var/log/messages`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on CentOS 7: `rsyslogd[42184]: BSD-style blocks are no longer supported in rsyslog, see http://www.rsyslog.com/g/BSD for details and a solution (Block '!dhcpd') [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2304 ]`